# An alternative word for "non-evaluativeness"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for an alternative word to use instead of "non-evaluativeness" which is long and not very common. Any ideas are appreciated.

---

Example:

Non-evaluativeness: Abstract should report the findings and data, it should not evaluate them.

Comment: "Low stakes" comes to mind.  We use this in education to describe testing that has little or no effect on a student's grade.

Comment: @StevenLittman: That doesn't sound appropriate to use in the example I just wrote. Does it?

Comment: heh that's one of the worst words I've ever seen!

Comment: As Brian has explained you want non-analytical.

Comment: The adjective 'raw' would in one of its  senses be spot on:<< 1d. Not having been subjected to adjustment, treatment, or analysis: raw data; the raw cost of production.>> [ [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rawness) ] But 'rawness' has a distinctly pejorative flavour hereabouts: <<rawness, incompleteness
n. the state of being crude and incomplete and imperfect; "the study was criticized for incompleteness of data but it stimulated further research"; "the rawness of his diary made it unpublishable" >> [ [lexipedia](http://www.lexipedia.com/english/rawness)].

Comment: it's not "raw", the thing desired is apparently a clear, cleaned-up, perhaps summarized, article (in English .. not data files) about the data .. not the raw data.  It's simply "non-analytical".  this can't become one of those questions with billions of comments about something so simple  :)

Comment: FTR HZ you probably (in a sense) wanted "evaluativeness" as that column heading.  Column headings could included "length" "tone" "evaluativeness".  In any event it is all moot.  **For God's sake, do not use evaluativeness or non-evaluativeness.**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to say that the Abstract should be *observational only*.  Or that it should be *non-analytical*.  Or that it should *draw no conclusions* from the data.

Comment: Yes, that is right. I'm writing a table to name four criteria that a good manuscript should meet before submission. My audience are students who want to write a paper in the future. The first column uses a noun to briefly indicate a good feature (Ex: Accuracy, non-evaluativeness, coherence and readability, conciseness). The second columns explains what I mean by that noun. I'm looking for a better noun to use instead of "non-evaluativeness" which is long and not commonly used. Is it clear what I'm looking for now? (I'm sorry if my question had been phrased ambiguously at first)

Comment: What you just said does not add anything to my understanding of your original question. You seem to be taking my answer above as a request for further explanation.  I realize I gave you adjectives rather than nouns, but that's all I have to offer. Is there a problem with using adjectives (readable, concise, coherent....)?

Answer (score 1):

**objectivity** (*noun*):

> the state of being objective, just, unbiased and not influenced by emotions or personal prejudices

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/objectivity); 
[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivity) (*see sections on scientific and journalistic objectivity)*

Answer (score 0):

Just give us a **readout** of the data, you know, a **nonjudgmental** report on what the heck is happening down at the bottom of shaft 39.

*If you want to be mean about it*:

Employees at your level lack the expertise to understand the implications of the information. We do **not** want another [Deepwater Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepwater_Horizon_oil_spill) on our hands here.